# BeautifulSoup4 .get('href') returns not only the href, but some junk as well

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program which searches "jopa olega" in Google and prints the url of the first result

This is the code I am running:

```
import requests, webbrowser, bs4

res = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + "jopa olega")
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")

links = soup.select('div#main > div > div > div > a')

href = links[0].get('href')  # <---- problem may be here
print(href)
```

What I expect to see:

```
https://pirozhki-ru.livejournal.com/990964.html
```

The actual output:

```
/url?q=https://pirozhki-ru.livejournal.com/990964.html&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjppYzLgKTlAhUMxosKHS5rDmkQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0UtLIaLS93pUQMWBngtgz7
```

This is the html of the link:

```
<a href="https://pirozhki-ru.livejournal.com/990964.html" 
   ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://pirozhki-ru.livejournal.com/990964.html&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiHn7P9h6TlAhURpIsKHRX5CRwQFjAAegQIAhAB">...
</a>
```

By the way, output is different each time. Does anyone know why that happens? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the full html of that `<a>` element?

Comment: is that the html from the page or the html in the response for that element? We need to see ideally both if different.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added the html. Could you please look at it?

Comment: works fine for me. What versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only one element, use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead and then call for `['href']` attribute:

```py
soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href'] # return one element rather than a list()
```

You can access attributes in the square brackets instead of using `get()`:

```py
links[0].get('href')
links[0]['href']
soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href'] # prints first link
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadged](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), otherwise Google will block your request eventually. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent` in request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

```py
requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + "jopa olega") # no need for + symbol
requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=jopa olega")
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "jopa olega"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
print(first_link)

# https://ar-ar.facebook.com/public/Jopa-Olega
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out how to scrape stuff since it's already done for the end-user. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want without thinking to bypass blocks from Google or maintain a parser over time.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "jopa olega",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] - first index of search results
first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
print(first_link)

# https://ar-ar.facebook.com/public/Jopa-Olega
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.